# How to set a input value of a form with jQuery Cookie

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

Hi I am learning jQuery and right now I am trying to use jQuery Cookie to set a form input value.

I have been able to set the cookie from a form using this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#saveForm").click(function() {
      $.cookie('myCookie', $("#element_1").val(), { expires: 365 });
    });
  });
</script>
```

I was able to verify the cookie using an alert like this:

```
<script>
  alert( $.cookie("myCookie") );
</script>
```

But after searching numerous posts on here, I was not able to find the same question and I have looked at numerous tutorials and can't find the code to set the value of a input field in a form. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the dom ready handler set the value using [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#saveForm").click(function () {
        $.cookie('myCookie', $el1.val(), {
            expires: 365
        });
    });

    //set the value of the cookie to the element element_1
    var $el1 = $("#element_1").val($.cookie("myCookie"))
});
```

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia not required

Comment: Thanks for your help, I accidentally deleted my previous comment, but putting it under your answer will not be helpful to anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#saveForm").click(function() {
      $.cookie('myCookie', $("#element_1").val(), { expires: 365 });
   });
   $("#element_1").val($.cookie('myCookie'));
});
```